# conditional formatiing rolling 6 weeks

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I would like to change the background color of a cell in my table based on incidents that have occurred within the last rolling 6 weeks. It would start from present date.

```
  Incident   date 
  g        14/01/2018
  e        15/01/2018 
  a        *02/02/2018
  b        05/02/2018
  c        02/03/2018*
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the background property of the cell or row to something like this.

=IIF(DateDiff(DateInterval.Day , Fields!YourDateColumn.Value, Today()) <=42, "Yellow", Nothing)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, this works perfectly, thank you